# IntPtr does not contain native value

Tags: c#, .net, interop, compact-framework, pinvoke

I have a native method that has to deliver a byte array to a .NET wrapper. The natove method looks like:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int WaitForData(unsigned char* pBuffer)
{
    return GetData(pBuffer);
}
```

GetData allocates a memory region using malloc and copies some data (a byte stream) into it. This byte stream was received via a socket connection. The return value is the length of pBuffer.

This method has to be called from .NET. The import declaration looks as follows:

```
[DllImport("CommunicationProxy.dll")]
public static extern int WaitForData(IntPtr buffer);
```

**[EDIT]**

The the P/Invoke Interop Assistant, that dasblinkenlight advised, translates the prototype to the following import signature:

```
public static extern  int WaitForData(System.IntPtr pBuffer)
```

The result is the same: ptr is 0 after calling the method.

**[/EDIT]**

Atfer the method was called, the result is extracted:

```
IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();
int length = Wrapper.WaitForData(ref ptr);

byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
{
    buffer[i] = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, i);
}
Wrapper.FreeMemory(ptr);
```

The problem is, that the managed variable ptr doesn't contain the value that the native varible pBuffer contains. `ptr` is always 0 when `Wrapper.WaitForData` returns although `pBuffer` pointed to an allocated memory area.

Is there a mistake in the prototype? How does a pointer to a byte array need to be marshalled?

Comment: I am nearly certain that the `DllImport` signature is not right. Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx), it comes with a tool that may make your life easier.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for the advise. Unfortunately it didn't help, but I updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` in the `DllImport` attribute?

Comment: Compact framework only supports CallingConvention.Winapi

Comment: Since you are not assigning `ptr` before the call, I'd try `public static extern int WaitForData([Out] IntPtr buffer);` in the signature, and `Wrapper.WaitForData(out ptr)` in the call. My exposure to interop is very limited, so this may not even compile. Did you try the tool from the article?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, I already used it to create the signature :)

Comment: I assume that you cannot change the signature of the native method, or the calling convention, right? Because if you could, the other option would be to allocate `buf = byte[MAX]` in your code, pass it as `ref byte buf` along with the value of `MAX` as the second parameter, obtain the actual `length` from the return, and copy the first `length` bytes from the buffer array that you have passed.

Comment: "I already used it to create the signature" this is odd - I thought `ref IntPtr` corresponded to `char **ptr`, not `char *ptr`... I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Well, I can change the signature. But I don't know how much data is transfered over the network. Besides that the target platform is an embedded device with limited memory so I try to avoid allocating big chunks of memory on spec.

Comment: The native declaration of `WaitForData` looks to be wrong. If `WaitForData` allocates a buffer and then returns that buffer through the `pBuffer` parameter then it needs to be `unsigned char**`

Comment: @PVitt If you are free to change the signature, you can model the API after [`fread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/), where you pass the buffer and its length to the API, and the API returns the actual length of data that it wrote into the buffer. This is very convenient, because it avoids allocation in the callee, thus sidestepping the buffer ownership issues.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I can change the signature, but I can't change the method GetData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to pass a reference to a pointer or 'double pointer' like that

```
__declspec(dllexport) int WaitForData(unsigned char** pBuffer)
```

and then change the value of the pointer(because it's passed by **value**)

```
*pBuffer = 'something'
```

other option - return the pointer(then you'll have to handle the int/length some other way)

btw that's why your automatically generated prototype looks like this(doesn't have out, ref modifiers)

Comment: Wouldn't then be `__declspec(dllexport) int WaitForData(unsigned char* pBuffer)` and `public static extern int WaitForData(byte buffer);` better?

Comment: nope - you need to change the signature of your native method as I showed above(or unsigned char* &pBuffer if you like that better) in order to change the value(this is the numeric address) of the pointer, if you don't do that you can just use it but not change it out of the method - thats the way c/c++ implements out/ref parameters